# How many ways exist to get from $A$ with the following conditions in the image?

Tags: combinatorics

**In the following image, how many ways exist to get from $A$ to $B$ if you can't go through the same point twice and you have to turn 5 times?**
[image]

***What I did***

Notice that we can only do 2 types of movements to get from A to B changing our direction 5 times:

A) Changing our direction every time we move (And getting to the next layer)

B)  Following one of the initial line, getting to the last layer, then change our direction (1) and then going a layer down (2), Then change our direction again (3), getting to the last layer (4) and get to $B$ (5)

For $A)$, starting from A, we can get to the next layer of 3 ways, selecting one of these, we have other 5 ways to go to the next layer (Changing our direction two times),then we have 10 ways to get to the last layer( Because, we can't go $B$ yet)(4 changes already), and then we just go to $B$, doing the last change
So we have $$3 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 \cdot = 150 $$

For $B)$, we have 3 initial lines, then we get to the last layer, we have 10 points to go (1), and then we get to the down layer (2), we have 9 points to go (3) (Not down $B$, to the point where we are, and the one we came of),then we get to the last layer (4) and we go to $B$ (5), so we have $$ 3 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 = 270$$

So we have  $$ 150 + 270 = 420$$
ways to get from $A$ to $B$

So I was wondering to know if my reasoning is correct, and if there are other ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is good, but there are more options. Numbering the circular tracks $1,2$ and $3$ from inside to out, and noting that changes of direction are onto or off a circular track, your option (A) visits tracks $1,2,3$ in that order and (B) is $3,2,3$ but also possible are $2,1,3$ and $3,1,3$.

Avoiding visiting the same point might get more complicated with the other options. I'm not completely sure you avoided that in assessing option (B) either.